# Using folder input to pull files into QGIS graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

My company has a script we use that pulls relevant terrain information from the web for an area and puts it into a specified folder. The files are .shp and .tiff files. Each time we use it, the file names are always the same.
I would like to create a process in the QGIS graphical modeler, where all you have to do is specify the folder, and the rest would be automated since the required files will always have the same name.
The image is an example process for this model, where the Upload Folder has all the desired files and the .tiff is an example of a consistent file name. The unit boundary is used for the extent in the raster calculator.
I am not sure how to connect the folder input to the rest of the model. I am not even sure how this input is supposed to work.
Is this process possible?
[image: Example of a process in the desired model]